# ncurses cannot print consecutive symbols

Tags: ncurses

If use the screen and keyboard attached to the server, it seems OK.
But if `ssh` to this server, it fails.
it is expected to print

```
+============================+
```

but it actually print

```
+=+
```

it seems multiple `=`s becomes one single `=`.
Can anyone tell me what the possible cause is?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what is your issue? For me, it just seems something like `print +=============+` change to `print +=+`, or does it affect behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Initialization begins with `initscr` (or `newterm`, if you read the manual page). As written, the program would print something to the screen, and exit without pausing (and if your terminal uses the alternate screen, the text would vanish or get replaced).

Quoting from `ncurses` manpages

> The  function  `initscr`  or  `newterm`  must  be  called to initialize the library before any of the other routines that  deal  with  windows  and screens are used.  The routine endwin(3x) must be called before exiting.

So, as soon as you declare your `main()`, call the function `initscr()` for initialization.

Comment: Yes. I actually called initscr() at the init stage.